# How to post an image as a File with Axios after Getting it as an Arraybuffer from an attachment

Tags: node.js, axios, content-type

As a POC I would like to make pictures of my receipts (gas, shop etc) and use a chatbot to send them to my accounting software. My problem has to do with the sending of the collected receipt (an image) to the accounting software using its API.

The first part (getting the attachment) results in an Arraybuffer with an image. I used one of the NodeJS samples for that (nr 15).

```
    const attachment = turnContext.activity.attachments[0];
    const url = attachment.contentUrl;
    let image;
    axios.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.headers['content-type'] === 'application/json') {
                response.data = JSON.parse(response.data, (key, value) => {
                    return value && value.type === 'Buffer' ? Buffer.from(value.data) : value;
                });
            }
            image = response.data;
        }
        ).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

I am struggling with the second part. Posting the image to the accounting software

```
const requestConfig = {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    };
    axios.post(postUrl, image, requestConfig)
        .then((response) => { console.log(response); }
        ).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
};
```

This results in 400. bad request. Probably the API needs a file and I cannot just send the buffer. I tested with Postman and the request is accepted by using application/x-www-form-urlencoded (by using a locally stored image file).

What is best practice to post an image retrieved in a bufferarray?

Comment: When you say "posting an image to the accounting software", you mean sending the image to a non-botframework API? Is the public API available? That should give you some clues to the accepted format.

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT they ask for header with content-type:multipart/mixed. Body should contain a file. In cURL example it states: -F file=@/tmp/upload.pdf. Guess I need to find a way to transform arraybuffer into a file and send it. Did not figure out how. Storing if on a filesystem temporarily as an intermediate step might be hard in case of Facebook channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your comment is right on the money that you need to convert it to a file first. The channel isn't an issue because the file will be stored wherever the bot is hosted. The [Attachments Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/15.handling-attachments) actually [has this code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/15.handling-attachments), which gets you close:

```js
fs.writeFile(localFileName, response.data, (fsError) => {
    if (fsError) {
        throw fsError;
    }
    // Send the file
    const url = '<yourApiUrl>';
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file',fs.createReadStream('<pathToFile>'), { knownLength: fs.statSync('<pathToFile>').size });
    const config = {
        headers: {
            ...formData.getHeaders(),
            'Content-Length': formData.getLengthSync()
        }
    };
    axios.post(url, forData, { headers });
});
```

I'm not super confident in the `// Send the file` section only because I can't test against your API. I got most of the code from [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/789#issuecomment-508114703).

Comment: Good morning. Your solution worked like a charm running locally. Once hosted on Azure, I got issues. Created a new question for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58306146/internal-server-error-om-azure-when-writing-file-from-buffer-to-filesystem. I you feel like it, I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: @Hessel We assigned your new issue to another support engineer this morning who has more bandwidth to provide assistance. Off-hand, I'm not sure what the problem might be, unless it doesn't like the location of where the file is being saved--a deployed bot uses a very different directory structure.

Comment: Tnx. I added some logging. Shouldn’t be hard to reproduce.

Comment: Just to comment on this code snippet, it looks like there's a mistake in the last line:  
`axios.post(url, forData, { headers });`

The variables being used seem to be incorrect, it looks like it ought to be:  
`axios.post(url, formData, config)`